# Laravel S3 Storage put returns boolean instead of path

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3, digital-ocean-spaces

I'm using DigitalOcean Spaces (S3 compatible) for storing my Laravel's app file.

Now I'm trying to make a .txt file inserting in it a text, with this code:

```
$file = Storage::disk('digitalocean')->put('generated-file/'.$title.'.txt', $content); 
return $file;
```

But instead of the path of the file, I get a boolean, so when I try to get the complete url with this method:

```
Storage::disk('digitalocean')->url($file);
```

I'm getting a wrong URL.
How I can achieve what I want to do? (Make a new txt file, don't upload an existing one, and getting his public url on the object storage).

Comment: `->put()` simply returns `true` or `false`, if you want to use `url()`, you'll need to return something like `'generated-file/'.$title.'.txt'` instead of `$file`.

Answer (score 0):

`put(...)` (or CRUD operations in general) will return the result of the operation in the form of a boolean most of the time - `true` indicating success and `false` indicating failure.

In this case, `$file` will contain a boolean value.

Return the file path and then pass that to `url(...)` to obtain the URL.

```
$filePath = 'generated-file/'.$title.'.txt';
$result = Storage::disk('digitalocean')->put($filePath, $content); 
return $filePath;
```

```
Storage::disk('digitalocean')->url($filePath);
```